# matching values in two same columns at different dataframes to get a corresponding value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have 2 dataframes , they have similar columns, but the second one is grouped(by column C and the aggregation function is max D, but I think it is not important), they look like that

```
df1 
       A     B     C    D
0     2     1     23   120
1     2     1     5    45
2     12    1     67   240
3     4     2     6    50
.
.
100   67    45     8   130

df2 
      A'    B'    C'    D'
0     2     1     23   120
1     14    2     30   200 
2     36    3     26   180
3     24    4     44   190
.
.
20    45    21    34   260
```

I want to match the values of the column A' in df2, with the values of A in df1, so I can get the corresponding values of column D in df1   (note, not all values of column A exist in column A')

the final output should look like that

```
      A         D
0     2        120
1     2        45
2     2        160
3     3        190 
4     3         50
5     3         70
.     
.    
.
80    23       145
```

Comment: This sounds like a `merge` job, but you did not specify how you handle duplicate data, e.g. you have several `2` in `df1.A`.

Comment: Yes I agree with @QuangHoang, the question is what is the logic for handling duplicates in the columns you want to match on.  Check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html to see if merge or concat works better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end you will get an extract of `df1` containing only columns `A` and `D` and rows for which `A` value exists in `df2["A'"]`. So I would use:

```
df1.loc[df1['A'].isin(df2['A1'])].sort_values('A').reset_index(drop=True)
```

(I do not want to play with `A'` so I used `A1` here)